# Implementation of std::experimental::observer_ptr (library fundamentals TS v2)

Tags: c++, pointers, c++17

I made an implementation of [std::experimental::observer_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr) (library fundamentals TS v2). `observer_ptr` basically behaves like a normal pointer and does no management of its target whatsoever (unlike `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`). It's usage is solely to indicate that it takes no ownership of the target object (it only observes it).

The implementation is simple and straight forward.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>


namespace tb
{
    template <typename T>
    class observer_ptr
    {
    public:
        using element_type = T;

        constexpr observer_ptr() noexcept = default;
        constexpr observer_ptr(std::nullptr_t) noexcept { }

        template <typename U, typename = std::enable_if<!std::is_same_v<element_type, U> && std::is_convertible_v<U*, element_type*>>>
        observer_ptr(observer_ptr<U> const& other) :
            observer_ptr(static_cast<element_type*>(other.get())) {}

        explicit observer_ptr(element_type* ptr) :
            _data(ptr) { }

        constexpr element_type* release() noexcept
        {
            auto* ptr = _data;
            _data = nullptr;
            return ptr;
        }

        constexpr void reset(element_type* p = nullptr) noexcept { _data = p; }

        constexpr void swap(observer_ptr& other) noexcept
        {
            using std::swap;
            swap(_data, other._data);
        }

        constexpr friend void swap(observer_ptr& lhs, observer_ptr& rhs) noexcept { lhs.swap(rhs); }

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr element_type* get() const noexcept { return _data; }

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr std::add_lvalue_reference_t<element_type> operator*() const { return *get(); }

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr element_type* operator->() const noexcept { return get(); }

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr explicit operator bool() const noexcept { return _data == nullptr; }

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr explicit operator element_type*() const noexcept { return get(); }

    private:
        element_type* _data = nullptr;
    };

    template <typename T>
    [[nodiscard]] observer_ptr<T> make_observer(T* ptr) noexcept
    {
        return observer_ptr<T>(ptr);
    }

    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    [[nodiscard]] bool operator==(observer_ptr<T1> const& p1, observer_ptr<T2> const& p2)
    {
        return p1.get() == p2.get();
    }

    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    [[nodiscard]] bool operator!=(observer_ptr<T1> const& p1, observer_ptr<T2> const& p2)
    {
        return !(p1 == p2);
    }

    template <typename T>
    [[nodiscard]] bool operator==(observer_ptr<T> const& p, std::nullptr_t) noexcept
    {
        return static_cast<bool>(p);
    }

    template <typename T>
    [[nodiscard]] bool operator==(std::nullptr_t, observer_ptr<T> const& p) noexcept
    {
        return static_cast<bool>(p);
    }

    template <typename T>
    [[nodiscard]] bool operator!=(observer_ptr<T> const& p, std::nullptr_t) noexcept
    {
        return !p;
    }

    template <typename T>
    [[nodiscard]] bool operator!=(std::nullptr_t, observer_ptr<T> const& p) noexcept
    {
        return !p;
    }

    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    [[nodiscard]] bool operator<(observer_ptr<T1> const& p1, observer_ptr<T2> const& p2)
    {
        return p1.get() < p2.get();
    }

    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    [[nodiscard]] bool operator>(observer_ptr<T1> const& p1, observer_ptr<T2> const& p2)
    {
        return p2 < p1;
    }

    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    [[nodiscard]] bool operator<=(observer_ptr<T1> const& p1, observer_ptr<T2> const& p2)
    {
        return !(p2 < p1);
    }

    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    [[nodiscard]] bool operator>=(observer_ptr<T1> const& p1, observer_ptr<T2> const& p2)
    {
        return !(p1 < p2);
    }
}
```

### Edit

Here is a sample usage

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct A 
{
    void hello() const { std::cout << "hello\n"; }    
};

// indicates that foo won't take ownership
void foo(tb::observer_ptr<A> const& ptr) { ptr->hello(); }

// does foo take ownership of ptr (especially if it were a member function)?
void foo(A* ptr) { ptr->hello(); }

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> manager;
    manager.emplace_back(new A);
    manager.emplace_back(new A);
    manager.emplace_back(new A);

    for (auto& a : manager)
    {
        foo(tb::observer_ptr(a.get()));
        foo(a.get());
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Some question that came to my mind:

1. Should I add constructor overloads for `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` (for convenience)?
2. I'm usually not a fan of implicit conversions but in this case I'm thinking about making the constructors implicit. This is justified by (a) `observer_ptr` is a fairly light weight type and (b) it doesn't change the behavior or affect the underlying pointer in any way. What do you think about that?

Comment: Could you provide examples of usage?

Comment: @pacmaninbw added an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. Don't prefix the data member with an underscore.  The rule about identifiers starting with an underscore are easy to get wrong.  In this case, just name it `data`.
2. You did not make the converting constructor and the raw pointer constructor `noexcept`.  They are `noexcept` according to the spec.
3. Don't use `element_type` everywhere, it's too long.  Just use `T`.
4. Don't breach the 80 character limit.  Scrolling is a bit annoying.

   > ```
   > template <typename U, typename = std::enable_if<!std::is_same_v<element_type, U> && std::is_convertible_v<U*, element_type*>>>
   > observer_ptr(observer_ptr<U> const& other)
   > ```

   The long line can be broken down.  `typename = std::enable_if` is useless — you probably meant `typename = std::enable_if_t`.  And the `!std::is_same_v<T, U>` is redundant because the copy constructor will always take precedence over this constructor:

   ```
   template <typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<U*, T*>>>
   observer_ptr(obverser_ptr<U> other) noexcept
       :data{other.get()}
   {
   }
   ```
5. The `release` function can be simplified with `std::exchange`:

   ```
   return std::exchange(data, nullptr);
   ```
6. The `operator bool` is getting the logic wrong — it should return `data != nullptr` instead.
7. The lines are getting a bit long for the observers.  I prefer writing them on separate lines:

   ```
   [[nodiscard]] constexpr std::add_lvalue_reference_t<T> operator*() const
   {
       return *get();
   }
   [[nodiscard]] constexpr T* operator->() const noexcept
   {
       return get();
   }
   ```
8. According to the spec, `operator<` should use `std::less` of the [composite pointer type](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr#def:composite_pointer_type) instead of the builtin `<` on pointers because the latter does not provide a strict total order.  So:

   ```
   template <typename T1, typename T2>
   [[nodiscard]] bool operator<(observer_ptr<T1> const& p1, observer_ptr<T2> const& p2)
   {
       using CP = /* work out the composite pointer type of T1* and T2* */;
       return std::less<CP>;
   }
   ```
9. Where's `std::hash`?  You need to specialize it.